# shiny dashboard with leaflet: cannot get server-side level counter to work

Tags: shiny, leaflet, dashboard

I am trying to build a shiny dashboard that cycles down polygon levels in leaflet. 
When a polygon is clicked, it adds 1 to the "level"indicator, and shows the polygon layer underneath the clicked polygon. When it reaches the bottom layer, it also shows the markers inside that polygon and cycles back to the top layer.

However, I cannot get the "level" indicator to work. It keeps resetting to zero cycling through the first and last level.

If anyone could help me fix this, it would be greatly appreciated!

Here is my code below:

```
server <- function(input, output) {

level<- 0
  # plot all polygons of the first level, which is 0
  output$map <- renderLeaflet({
    leaflet(data = wijk_sf) %>%
      #setView(lng = 4.473719, lat = 51.88956, zoom = 11) %>%
      addProviderTiles("Stamen.Terrain") %>%
      addPolygons(color = "black",
                  fillColor = "darkgreen",
                  fillOpacity = 0.7,
                  label = ~GEBDNAAM,
                  layerId = ~GEBDNAAM
                  ) 
  })

  observe(
    {click = input$map_shape_click
     p <- input$map_shape_click
     if(is.null(click)){
       return()
     }else if((p$id %in% wijk_vec) & level == 0){ 


   level<- 1

 # plot polygon level 0 here and set level to 1


     }else if((p$id %in% buurt_vec) & level == 1){
     level <- 2

     #  if level == 1, plot polygon level 1 here and set level to 2

     }else if((p$id %in% buurt_vec) & level == 2){

      level<- 0


     # if level == 2, plot polygon level 2 here and set level to 0

     }else{

     level <- 0

     # if all else fails, set level to 0 and plot the standard level 0 map

      leafletProxy('map') %>%
      clearShapes() %>%
        clearMarkers() %>%
        setView(lng = 4.473719, lat = 51.88956, zoom = 11) %>%
      addPolygons(data = df[,level])

    }
  )

}
```

Comment: There is a lot going on here, can you please edit into a [mcve] so that others can better understand the question?

Comment: Since the leaflet map is not the focus here, I deleted those and gave a small description instead. Its difficult to find example polygons and I can't share the ones I have. The problem is: The code should cycle through the various if else() statements, with each click displaying the polygons underneath the polygons of the current level. When the bottom is reached, it should reset to the top.

However, the 'level''  variable keeps resetting to 0, so the code cycles between the first and last level. I cant get the level variable to work properly.

Comment: I fixed my own issue/ Problem was that the level variable doesn't get updated outside of the observe function. Double arrows solved it by assigning it to the global environment.

Comment: Thats great! You should write that up as an answer so that others can find it if they are having that issue. https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 0):

updating a value defined outside an observe function cannot be updated inside the observe function, unless you use double arrows (<<-) to assign into the scope of the global environment.

This means, if you need a counter of some sort that updates every time an observe function is called in your dashboard, do it like this:

counter<- 1

observe({click = input$map_shape_click

counter <<- counter + 1
})